# Why is my gridview not showing on my page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-gridview

I'm trying to display the country by continent in a dynamic way so I can reuse my widget for other continent but my GridView don't work, nothing is showing either in my debug console or my page can someone help me identify the problem so I can solve it?
Is it from the Dynamic list I try to use to display the children? Any better way to achieve what I want to do?

[image: It should look like that]

Thanks a lot!!

code :

```
class ShowByContinent extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final String continent;

  ShowByContinent({
    required this.continent,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _ShowByContinentState();
}

class _ShowByContinentState extends ConsumerState<ShowByContinent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List continentCountry = [];
    showByContinent() {
      countries_info.forEach((key, value) {
        if (value["continent"] == widget.continent) {
          continentCountry = key.split(",");
        }
      });
    }

    showByContinent();
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: continentCountry.length,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: continentCountry[index],
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

parent Widget :

```
class _ResultsState extends ConsumerState<Results> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("BRAVO You found : "),

              Text(
                "${countryName.length}/${countries_info.length} country",
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              ProgessBar(
                  totalCounrty: countries_info.length,
                  guessedCountry: countryName.length),
              Column(
// Level
                children: [
                  Text("Dificulty:"),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.star),
                      Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined),
                      Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined),
                      Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined)
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text("My score : ${countryName.length} pts"),
                  Text("My best score : $bestScore pts"),
                  Text("+ $difScore"),
                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Play Again?")),
                ],
              ),
              ShowByContinent(
                continent: "Asia",
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the parent widget structure, can you include sample snippet from scaffold body

Comment: Yes I'll edit my post

Comment: Can you print `continentCountry.length` if it getting>0

Comment: It print 1 when I ask for the length but it print all of the country when I just print the variable each country is between [] when the print is call in the function but if I call continentCountry after calling the function it print only the last country.. I don't get why haha

Comment: ok Let me give you an example ,how it should be structured.. btw how you are getting `countries_info`

Answer (score 0):

Don't declarer variable inside build method, try

```dart
class _ShowByContinentState extends ConsumerState<ShowByContinent> {
  List continentCountry = [];
  showByContinent() {
    countries_info.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value["continent"] == widget.continent) {
        continentCountry = key.split(",");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showByContinent();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: continentCountry.length,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: continentCountry[index],
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why should I not declare a variable inside build method? 
tried your code but I have an error showing : " Expected a value f type 'Widget?', but got one of type 'String'..

Comment: From where can come this error? Do you have any idea?

Comment: this error means you need to use Text Widget to represent on UI , try `child: Text( continentCountry[index],)`

Comment: Oooh I feel dumb now! Thanks! Sorry for the stupid question I've been learning for like a month or so hahaha

Comment: It's ok, my I didn't notice last comment earlier. More on http://flutter.dev/

Comment: Thank you very much! To display all the list the best way would be a spread operator?

Comment: that might not be needed, it depends on usecase.

Comment: What do you mean by usecase? Because here I'm using a text widget but it doesn't accept list right? So if I want to display all the countries how should I do?

Comment: ig `continentCountry[index]` is single string

Comment: Yes and it just display the last item of the list but I want it to display all of them in the gridview like in the photo. I tried the spread operator but it doesn't work, neither that using a cast? like : `continentCountry as String`

Comment: I think the issue is `  continentCountry = key.split(",");` which will be `continentCountry .addAll(key.split(","));`

Comment: the .addAll can be use to add every key or valu from a map to a list? 
It solved my issu thank you so much! Just want to understand it as I've never seen it before :)